# OnPropertyChange not firing IDataErrorInfo.this[]

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm attempting to catch errors using IDataErrorInfo, but changes in the bound data are not firing IdataErrorInfo.this[].  I believe it's due to the way I'm binding data to the textbox.

My textbox Text is bound to a source as follows:

```
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="8 0 0 0"
                   Text="{Binding LimitsConfiguration.ThisItemMax, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
                   Style="{StaticResource ValidatableTextBoxStyle}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="40" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

The StaticResource is defined by:

```
    <Style  x:Key="ValidatableTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

The source is defined as follows.  Note that his object is not created in the same namespace and has about 9 different string members defined in it.

```
    public LimitsConfig LimitsConfiguration
    {
        get { return _limitsConfiguration; }
        set
        {
            _limitsConfiguration  = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LimitsConfiguration");
        }
    }
```

And my IDataErrorInfo.this[] implementation is as follows:

```
  string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
  {
       get
       {
            string result = String.Empty;
            string limitsErrorMsg = "Enter a numeric value for ";
            int i;

            if (propertyName == "LimitsConfiguration")
            {
                if (propertyName == LimitsConfiguration.ThisItemMax.ToString())
                {
                    string msg = limitsErrorMsg + "Max Itmes";
                    string field = LimitsConfiguration.ThisItemMax.ToString();

                    result = ValidateLimit(field, msg);
                }

             }

            return result;
        }
   }
```

The implementation of IDataInfo.this[string propertyName] is never hit.  However, the IDataErrorInfo implementation works when textbox text is bound to a string type.  Therefore, I believe the issue is due to the binding of a member of the source (Binding LimitsConfiguration.WaypointsMax), but I'm not sure how to get around it other than create public memebers for all items in the LimitsConfiguraton object (which I'd rather not do).

I am new to WPF, so any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The text box does not listen for property changed events on the class that contains the `LimitsConfiguration` property. Instead it listens on the property changed events of the `LimitsConfig` class, because this is the class that contains the property that is bound to the text box.